# Note: fdisk truncates, sfdisk truncates, fields missing. Now what?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, external-hard-drive

A drive was purchased.
WD (Western Digital) M.2 sata 1TB 2280

drive is raw from store
drive is not partitioned
drive is not formatted, no filesystem, yet

with kubuntu 22.04

```
lsblk --version  
lsblk from util-linux 2.37.2
```

```
lsblk -ido KNAME,TYPE,SIZE,MODEL |grep -i 'sd\|disk\|size'  

KNAME   TYPE   SIZE MODEL  
sda     disk 931.5G WD Blue SA510 M.2 2280 1000GB
```

.

```
fdisk --version   
fdisk from util-linux 2.37.2
```

```
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda   
 
Disk /dev/sda: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: WD Blue SA510 M.
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

.

```
sfdisk --version  
sfdisk from util-linux 2.37.2
```

```
sudo sfdisk -l /dev/sda  
Disk /dev/sda: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: WD Blue SA510 M.
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
sfdisk: cannot open  : No such file or directory
```

Note difference, Disk model:

```
WD Blue SA510 M.2 2280 1000GB   lsblk from util-linux 2.37.2   
WD Blue SA510 M.                fdisk from util-linux 2.37.2  
WD Blue SA510 M.               sfdisk from util-linux 2.37.2
```

Who to notify?
Who is the code writer?
Where to post this?  web page?
How can the fdisk code writer be notified of above missing information?

--